# Remove object in array by key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove object by key in JavaScript

here is example of array

```
{
Account Manager: {selected: true}
Arrival: {selected: true}
Client: {selected: true}
Client Contact: {selected: true}
Created: {selected: true}
Created by: {selected: true}
Departure: {selected: true}
Destination: {selected: true}
Keywords: {selected: true}
Status: {selected: true}
}
```

now i'm trying to remove status and client from this array but i don't know how to make it. 
I've tried with this:

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] == 'Status' || list[i] == 'Client') {
       list.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: the example you've shared is not an array it's an Object

Comment: @iam.Carrot is correct , its an object not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided sample is an `Object` and not an `array`. Since you're using `AngularJS` you can directly use `JavaScript` to remove the key from the object.

Below is a sample by simply using the `delete()` method

```js
 const _object = {
      "Account Manager": { selected: true },
      "Arrival": { selected: true },
      "Client": { selected: true },
      "Client Contact": { selected: true },
      "Created": { selected: true },
      "Created by": { selected: true },
      "Departure": { selected: true },
      "Destination": { selected: true },
      "Keywords": { selected: true },
      "Status": { selected: true }
    }

    delete _object["Status"];

    console.log(_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use reduce function for that -:

```
let newList = Object.keys(oldList).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if(key !== 'Status' || key !== 'Client'){
        acc[key] = oldList[key]
    }
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `delete` keywaord for that -:

```
delete object["keyName"];
```

This will remove that specific key...